# Delay in the transmission of knowledge to poorer countries

Tags: macroeconomics

> Assume the world consists of two regions, the North and South with the following production functions and technology lags in the south by $\tau$ years:
>
> $$ Y_N = A_N (t) (1-a_L) L_N; \; \; \dot{A}_N = a_L L_N A_N (t)$$
>
> $$ Y_S = A_S (t) L_S  ; \; \; A_S = A_N (t - \tau) $$
>
> The growth rate of output per worker in the North is $3 \% \; year^{-1}$ and if $a_L \simeq 0$, what $\tau$ must be for output per worker in the North to exceed that in the South by a factor of 10?

For output per worker in the north to exceed that in the south by a factor of ten:

$$ 10 = \frac{Y_N/L_N}{Y_S/L_S} = \frac{A_N(t)(1-a_L)}{A_S(t)} $$

with $a_L \simeq 0$ this goes to

$$ \to \frac{A_N (t)}{A_N (t-\tau)}$$

My book says this is equal to $e^{0.03 \tau}$

Could someone explain where this last result comes from please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the notation used, labor quantity appears to be constant. Then the only source of growth of output is the growth in $A_N(t)$, and they will have the same growth *rate*. Take logarithms and then time derivatives on the output per capita equation to see this.
Then remember introductory differential equations on how to express $x(t)$ as a function of $x(0)$ and a constant growth rate. And don't forget to explicitly solve for the **10**-factor difference required, at the end.